# Developing a function to print a grid in python

Tags: python

I Just started programming with python and I've been tasked in printing a grid in python that looks as follows (image is attached). I'm really stumped on how i would achieve this through defining a function:

[Picture of Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyTur.png)

```
def display_game(game, grid_size):
```

The argument (game) is the strings that represent the cells in the game i.e (~),
whilst the grid_size represents the size of the grid, i.e 7 would correspond to a 7x7 grid.

I know string splicing, for loops and print statements would be viable, i just don't know how to piece it together.

Any help would be much appreciated, Cheers.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Do you have a general plan, pseudocode, something like that?

Comment: The issue is i don't know how to produce the image attached through using python and defining a function.

Comment: Isn’t that what was already said in your post?

Comment: I also said that i was new to python, one week to be exact, i just didn't know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

```
def display_game(game, grid_size):
    c = 65

    # First row
    print(f"  ", end='')
    for j in range(grid_size):
        print(f"| {j+1} ", end='')
    print("| ")
    print((grid_size*4+4)*"-")

    # Other rows
    for i in range(grid_size):
        print(f"{chr(c+i)} ", end='')
        for j in range(grid_size):
            print(f"| {game} ", end='')
        print("| ")
        print((grid_size*4+4)*"-")


display_game('~', 7)
```

```
  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 
--------------------------------
A | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | 
--------------------------------
B | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | 
--------------------------------
C | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | 
--------------------------------
D | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | 
--------------------------------
E | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | 
--------------------------------
F | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | 
--------------------------------
G | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | 
--------------------------------
```

Comment: Most welcome, chr() returns a character for an integer. The alphabet starts at 65. To loop through, the printed character just starts at 65+0 ... 65+6.

Comment: If i wanted to change this block of code so that i could input any grid_size and it would output the corresponding grid, how would i achieve this, thanks.

Comment: Your code and mine solve the problem but we were both voted down! I wonder why??

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
def display_game(game, grid_size):
    header_row = ''
    row = ''
    for x in range(1,grid_size+1):
        header_row = header_row + '|' + str(x)
        row = row + '|' + game 
    print(header_row + '|')
    print('-' * (len(row)+1))
    char = 64
    for x in range(1,grid_size+1):
        char = char  +1 
        print(chr(char) + row + '|')


display_game('~', 7)
```

This should give the following output:

[image]